# Node.js fs: detecting when outStream finishes writing

Tags: node.js

I'm using node zlib.createGzip to compress a huge string.

Using streams, I do the following operation.  I would like to know when the outStream is finished writing data so I can invoke a callback.
I know how to detect the inStream 'end' event but can't find an equivalent for the writable outStream.

Any suggestions?

```
var gzOption = {
    level: zlib.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION, 
    memLevel: zlib.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION
}
var gzip = zlib.createGzip(gzOption) 
inputStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
outStream = fs.createWriteStream(gzFilePath);
inputStream.pipe(gzip).pipe(outStream);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try listening to the `finish` event of the writeable stream? It's documented here: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish

> When the end() method has been called, and all data has been flushed to the underlying system, this event is emitted.